# Change height of footer css

Tags: html, css

Problem: I don't know how to change the height of the footer when using `reset.css`, the height property for the footer div doesn't change anything.

You can clone this locally and [check it out here](https://github.com/eveo/Sam)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Your website content here.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; 2013 Friend | Design and Development. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

CSS - style.css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

#footer {
    background: #444444;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

RESET.css

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you match the negative bottom margin on `.wrapper` to the height of your footer, the entire footer should show.

Or, if you're going for a footer that floats at the bottom of the page, you can do this:

```css
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    /* padding the footer adds 40 to footer height */
    padding-bottom: 140px;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #444444;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Your website content here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2013 Friend | Design and Development. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

matching height to `.content` padding

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the d when you're defining the footer

http://plnkr.co/edit/ULC8NHYMqmP240OW2z1d?p=preview

Comment: That still doesn't solve the problem at all. Changing the height when I fixed the index still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Just noticed it's not coming out right in Firefox. However, it's only this way because it's not allowing vertical scrolling. If you remove the min-height on .wrapper, you'll find that the height changes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 27, the bottom margin on .wrapper is limiting the visible height of #footer. The footer does get taller when the height property is increased, but the extra height (outside the 4em worth of .wrapper) is hidden beyond the initial viewport height.

So, it's performing exactly as specified: .wrapper takes up all but the bottom 4em of the viewport, and the #footer has its own height unrelated to that 4em.